# Installing SerpentAI error

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to install SerpentAI, and I've followed the steps word for word (except the Redis one), but I keep [getting this error.](https://gyazo.com/c5de9551386ba5fcae9739814a7c39e4)

I think it's because I didn't install Redis, but I don't know how to do that. I downloaded it from GitHub, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

[Here's a link to the documentation I was following, if it helps.](https://github.com/SerpentAI/SerpentAI/wiki/Windows-Installation-Guide) I was right at the "run pip install serpentai"

Thanks so much!

Comment: The link to your error is broken.  Please fix the link AND post the error text here.  Thanks.

Comment: The link is working fine for me, and I'm not about to manually write out a 400 character error message.

Comment: The link is working now because user @hoefling fixed it.  Having some of the error text will keep your question viable in case gyazo.com is unavailable.  It shouldn't be too much work.

Comment: Ok then... Command "C:\users\owner\anaconda3\envs\serpent\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\owner\appdata\local\\temp\\pip-build-gj76fsev\\pyyaml\\setup.py' f=getattr(tokenize 'open',open(_file_) (contiues, but seems unimportant) failed with error code 1 in c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-gj76fsev\pyyaml\